# wpf entity framework 6 lazy loading false still loads data from database

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, data-binding

I have 3 models:

```
public class producer
{
 public int producer_id { get; set; }
 public string name { get; set; }

 public ObservableCollection<machine> machines {get; set }

 public producer()
  {
    machines = new ObservableCollections<machine>();
  }
}

public class machine
{
 public int machine_id { get; set;}

 public int producer_id { get; set; }
 public producer producer { get; set; }

 public int machineType_id { get; set; }
 public virtual machineType { get; set; }

 public string machineNumber { get; set; } 
}

public class machineType
{
 public int machineType_id { get; set; }
 public string name { get; set; }
}
```

My dbcontext looks like this:

```
public class context : DBontext
{
 public dbSet<producer> producers { get; set; }
 public dbset<machine> machines { get; set; }
 public dbSet<machineType> machineTypes { get; set; }

   public context()
    {
      this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }

   protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("public");
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

In my viewmodel i call:

```
  public class vmList
  {     
   public ObservableCollection<machine> machines { get; set; }
    public vmList()
     {
       using (context c = new context())
        {
         c.machines.Include(o=> o.machineType)).LoadAsync();
         machines = c.machines.Local;
        }
     }
  }
```

In my view i have listView:

```
  <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding machines}>
   <ListView.View>
    <GridView> 
          <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding producer.name, IsAsync=True}" Width="Auto">                    
            </GridViewColumn>

            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding machineType.name, IsAsync=true}" Width="Auto">                    
            </GridViewColumn>
   etc...
    </GridView>
   </ListView.View>
  </ListView>
```

My conection to database right now is really slow, so everything is visible. It looks like it loads two time data from database. first loading is when c. ...LoadAsync() is ececuted, when I debug code, I see everting in machines collection, but after continue data in listView shows partially, cell after cell. When I disconnect computer from network after machines collection is loaded, then programs hangs.
With IsAsync = False in Bindings, UI freezes until all data will loaded...

My question is, why it loads data twice, when lazy-loading is false and how to improve that (if I have filed collection, why it is not enough?